# Trying to hide all visible divs and show just the selected one

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, toggle

The following code works to toggle visibility on and off, but I want to be able to hide any visible div and show only the one that is visible.  Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="main">

    <div id="hiddena">
    </div>
    
    <div id="hiddenb">
    </div>
    
    <div id="hiddenc">
    </div>
    
    <div id="hiddend">
    </div>
    
    <div id="hiddene">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="buttona">
    <button type=submit onclick="switchVisible('hiddena');"></button>
</div>

<div id="buttonb">
    <button type=submit onclick="switchVisible('hiddenb');"></button>
</div>

<div id="buttonc">
    <button type=submit onclick="switchVisible('hiddenc');"></button>
</div>

<div id="buttond">
    <button type=submit onclick="switchVisible('hiddend');"></button>
</div>

<div id="buttone" class="tall">
    <button type=submit onclick="switchVisible('hiddene');"></button>
</div>
```

And here is the script...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function switchVisible(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}

</script>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or additions to the script that could accomplish this?

Comment: You should give them all a common class name then you can [select all of the elements with that class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and hide them all. Then you just handle the one you selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would it be a problem to hide all of them at once and then show up only the one you want?

```
function hide_them() {
    var divsList = ["hiddena", "hiddenb", "hiddenc", "hiddend", "hiddene"]
    divsList.forEach(function (element) {
        element.style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
}
```

finally, just call the hide_them function in the begining of your func:

```
function switchVisible(id) {
   hide_them();
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Another way is to select elements by tag, and hide them all (this is not pretty good way because when your code grows up, it may cause unwanted problems)

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions here

1. Never Mix your markup with javascript. You might consider binding the onclick at javascript by using addeventlistener or jQuery bind
2. Id should always be unique. If you want to have multiple elements the same name ,you might consider using class,because document.getelementsbyclassname always returns an array
   3.In your show/hide logic, you are checking if the element is "block" or "none". When the element is displayed, by default element.style.display would be "" not "block"

check the following code snippet

```js
function switchVisiblebyId(id){
  var element=document.getElementById(id);
var displayStyle=element.style.display;
  if(displayStyle==="" || displayStyle==="block"){
    element.style.display="none";
  }
  else{
    element.style.display="";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hiddena">
  div1
    </div>

    <div id="hiddenb">
      div2
    </div>

    <div id="hiddenc">
      div3
    </div>

    <div id="hiddend">
      div4
    </div>

    <div id="hiddene">
      div5
    </div>


<div id="buttona">button1
    <button type=submit onclick="switchVisiblebyId('hiddena');"></button>
</div>

<div id="buttonb">button2
    <button type=submit onclick="switchVisiblebyId('hiddenb');"></button>
</div>

<div id="buttonc">button3
    <button type=submit onclick="switchVisiblebyId('hiddenc');"></button>
</div>

<div id="buttond">button4
    <button type=submit onclick="switchVisiblebyId('hiddend');"></button>
</div>

<div id="buttone" class="tall">button5
    <button type=submit onclick="switchVisiblebyId('hiddene');"></button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This seems to have the same result as my original code where the buttons are used to toggle on and off.